# Handling windowStateChanged - Tab change in IE extension

Tags: .net, c++, internet-explorer, atl

I have the following in my IE extension to handle when a tab is switched in IE, etc.
[ATL project, VS2008, C++ using IDispEventImpl]

```
SINK_ENTRY_EX(1, DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, DISPID_WINDOWSTATECHANGED,WindowStateChanged)
.
.
.    
void WindowStateChanged (DWORD dwFlags, DWORD dwValidFlagsMask);
.
.
.
.
void CHelloWorld::WindowStateChanged (DWORD dwFlags, DWORD dwValidFlagsMask){
    //I don't do anything here right now. Even if I have some piece of code like
    //ATLTRACE, IE just hangs

}
```

Whenever I run my code, the IE stops working (I get a dialog "Internet Explorer has stopped working") What am I doing wrong? What might be missing in my code?
Or, Is this a bug in IE8? I'm working on Windows 7 (eval) BTW.

Comment: You'll want to run your code under a debugger to determine where the crash is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How stupid of me. I missed this: STDMETHODCALLTYPE
So my code is:

```
SINK_ENTRY_EX(1, DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, DISPID_WINDOWSTATECHANGED,WindowStateChanged)
.
.
.    
void STDMETHODCALLTYPE WindowStateChanged (DWORD dwFlags, DWORD dwValidFlagsMask);
.
.
.
.
void STDMETHODCALLTYPE CHelloWorld::WindowStateChanged (DWORD dwFlags, DWORD dwValidFlagsMask){
    //I don't do anything here right now. Even if I have some piece of code like
    //ATLTRACE, IE just hangs

}
```

Now, IE hangs no more. :)